# Filter Facebook notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a Greasemonkey script or something for Firefox which will either filter, or indicate my notifications in Facebook such that I can either:

- See only notifications for items on which I have actually commented (as opposed to those I have simply 'liked')
- Highlight notifications for items on which I have actually commented so I can distinguish them from ones I have merely 'liked'

After a quick search in GM, I see ones to color code matching notifications for the same post, but I'd like to either filter out or dim out notifications for posts on which I haven't actually commented.

Other solutions besides Greasemonkey are also welcome.

Comment: I wish FB would provide better controls over a lot of things, this included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has actually been taken care of, now that FB groups notifications by post.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [better facebook](http://betterfacebook.net/) it's a great tool with many options to control facebook status and other things. Works with chrome, firefox, opera and safari.

Comment: Well, it doesn't do exactly what I want, but it *does* have previews when you hover your notifications, and that does help quite a bit!  :)  . I did turn off a lot of the other stuff though as ALL the default functionality seemed to create quite a performance hit.